# Filling char array with snprintf()

Tags: c

I am trying to fill a char array with values under conditions. The problem is I can not use `snprintf()` not properly.

```
    char staedte[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    char laender[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    int bewohner[MAX_LAENGE_ARR];


    char *p = (char*) malloc(len);
    if (p == NULL){
        perror("malloc failed while allocating an array of chars.");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LAENGE_ARR; i++) {
        if(strcmp(bundesland,laender[i]) == 0 && bewohner[i] >= anzahl){
            snprintf(p,MAX_LAENGE_STR,"Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner. \n", staedte[i],bewohner[i]);
            snprintf(&p[i],MAX_LAENGE_STR,"Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner. \n", staedte[i],bewohner[i]);
        }
    }
    free(p);      
}
```

Comment: bewohner is integer but others are char.

Comment: Oh duh, eyes deceived me. Please add an example of the file you're reading, the output you expect to see and the output you are currently seeing

Comment: i edited my question. my problem is about the usage of char array and snprintf()

Comment: Please try to post a [mcve]. There's a lot of code here that isn't relevant to the problem. I think it will be easier for you to find out what's wrong if you strip the code right down to the bare minimum.

Comment: Tormund asked me to add more code.

Comment: What does `read_file` return? Usually snprintf is used like: `char p[256]; const size_t p_size = 256; const size_t p_pos = 0;` and then `p_pos = snprintf(&p[p_pos], p_size - p_pos, "some string");`. Passing `MAX_LAENGE_STR` to `p` when `p` is `malloc(len);` may overflow. snprintf returns the number of characters written, so you can know when to start the next snprint.

Comment: In short, my question is, how can I fill a char array in a for loop with snprintf()

Comment: what is the contents of the local header file: `input3.h`?

Comment: regarding: `char *p = (char*)malloc(len);`  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert a blank line between code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default`  2) insert an appropriate space inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Comment: OT:  regarding these kinds of statements: `printf("Aufruf: %s <anzahl> <bundesland>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Beispiel: %s 100 Bayern\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Klein-/GroÃŸschreibung beachten!\n");` error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using: `fprintf( stderr, "...", argv[0] );`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1)  Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{',   Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: @user3629249 The size used in malloc should be multiplied by the size of the target of the pointer. So if you're assigning to `char *`, you use `len * sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snprintf()` returns the number of bytes that it wrote to the string. You can use this to increment the position where you write the next line.

```
int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LAENGE_ARR; i++) {
    if(strcmp(bundesland,laender[i]) == 0 && bewohner[i] >= anzahl){
        int written = snprintf(p + offset, len - offset, Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner. \n", staedte[i], bewohner[i]);
        printf("%s : %d\n",staedte[i] , bewohner[i]);
        offset += written;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you're calling `snprintf()` twice. I removed the one that just writes to `p`.

Since the length of the `p` string is `len` bytes, you should use that when specifying the maximum amount to write in `snprintf()`, not `MAX_LANGE_STR`. You have to subtract `offset` from it, since each write is further in the string and there's less room left after it.

Comment: I wasnt actually calling it twice, I was just showing two different ways I was trying :)

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
    if( strcmp( bundesland,laender[i] ) == 0 && bewohner[i] >= anzahl)
    {
            snprintf(p,MAX_LAENGE_STR,"Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner. \n", staedte[i],bewohner[i]);
            snprintf(&p[i],MAX_LAENGE_STR,"Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner. \n", staedte[i],bewohner[i]);

            printf("%s : %d\n",staedte[i] , bewohner[i]);
    }
```

the first call to `snprintf()` keeps overlaying the first entry in the `p[]` array

suggest:

```
    char buffer[MAX_LAENGE_STR+1];
    p[0] = '\0';
```

then in the loop

```
    if( strcmp( bundesland,laender[i] ) == 0 && bewohner[i] >= anzahl)
    {
            snprintf( buffer, MAX_LAENGE_STR, "Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner. \n", staedte[i],bewohner[i]);
            strcat( p, buffer );

            printf("%s : %d\n",staedte[i] , bewohner[i]);
    }
```

I'll leave it to you to add the checking that the buffer `p[]` is not overflowed.

Comment: `p` is not an array of pointers, it's a pointer to a `char` array.

Comment: @Barmar.  Ok, I'll modify my answer accordingly

Comment: but this way, there is always a empty line at the beginning.

Comment: @aomerk, no, the use of `strcat()` will place the data at the next available location in `p`

Comment: @aomerk,  I have no idea what the 'Bug' is referring to.  The question states that there are 8 lines to be printed

Comment: Sorry. The bug says there is an extra blank line at the beginning.

Comment: @aomerk,  The code I proposed does not add any extra '\n' characters.

Comment: any blank line  at the beginning of the output is NOT caused by the posted answer.  As requested in the comments to the question, please post a [mcve]  Then we can debug the 'blank line'